# There is any way to encapsulate a SOAP object using WebClient framework?

Tags: xml, soap, webclient

```
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <ns1:Security xmlns:ns1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soapenv:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next" soapenv:mustUnderstand="0">
         <ns1:UsernameToken>
            <ns1:Username>XXXXX</ns1:Username>
            <ns1:Password>XXXXXX</ns1:Password>
         </ns1:UsernameToken>
      </ns1:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <consultarPosicaoCotistaOnOfflineFundoRequest>
         <filtro>
            <cdCotista>2780008158</cdCotista>
            <icSnUltimaPosicao>S</icSnUltimaPosicao>
            <ictpSaldo>F</ictpSaldo>
         </filtro>
      </consultarPosicaoCotistaOnOfflineFundoRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am trying to consume a webservice and I need to send in the body of my request this soap object above ... but I got this error below:

```
Content type 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8' not supported for bodyType=com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.Message1_1Impl
```

And that's the function I am trying to use:

```
Mono<String> monoResponse =  webClient()
                .post()
                .header("SOAPAction", "")
                .header("User-Agent", "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/12.0.1)")
                .header("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=UTF-8")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .acceptCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
                .bodyValue(soapMessage)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class);


        monoResponse.block();
```

By any chance Do I can send this object through this way?!

Answer (score 0):

The namespace `https://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/` is SOAP 1.2, for which the correct content-type is `application/soap+xml`. Try changing the specified content type to this value. Content type `text/xml` is correct for SOAP 1.1.

Comment: I just copied the wrong object ... I have to use SOAP 1.1 that is why I am trying this way.